# UIView Animation iPhone (obtaining information on the frame dynamically)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a `UIView` called *goalBar* which is being animated by increasing the size of the frame according to a float value called *destination*:

```
CGRect goalBarRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, destination, 29);

[UIView beginAnimations:@"goal" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];

goalBar.frame = goalBarRect;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The animation works perfectly and the rectangular view increases its width over the course of the animation (from *0* to the value for *destination*).

However, I wish to be able to extract the values for the frame of the `UIView` being animated (i.e. *goalBar*) as the animation takes place. By that I mean that I wish to place the value of the width for the animated frame in a separate `UILabel` so that the user sees a counter that provides the width of the `UIView` as it's being animated.

Any help on how to do the above would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

How about observing the frame property of the view. So that you get callbacks when it changes.

See Key-Value Observing.

Comment: The notification is only given at the end of the animation. What I really need is a runing commentary on the size of the frame as it is expanding (i.e. during the animation).

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this and it seems that it is not possible to get updates on the state of the components being animated during the UIView animation process.